# Find a parse error in Octave

Tags: octave, parse-error

I wrote a simple code in Octave,but it keeps reporting parse error which I can't find.The code is

```
X = magic(3)
m = size(X, 1)
p = zeros(m, 1)
theta = [1;2;1]
hypo = 1./(1.+exp(-X*theta));
for i = 1:m
    if hypo(i) > 0.5
        p(i) = 1;
    else
        p(i) = 0;
end
```

and Octave reports

```
 parse error near line 12 of file F:/my document/machine learning/machine-learning-ex2/ex2/new 1.m

  syntax error



error: source: error sourcing file 'F:/my document/machine learning/machine-learning-ex2/ex2/new 1.m'
error: parse error
```

But,there is nothing in line 12.The last line is 11.I don't know where is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `end` to terminate the `if` statement. The correct code should be like this:

```matlab
X = magic(3)
m = size(X, 1)
p = zeros(m, 1)
theta = [1;2;1]
hypo = 1./(1.+exp(-X*theta));
for i = 1:m
    if hypo(i) > 0.5
        p(i) = 1;
    else
        p(i) = 0;
    end            % <-- you forgot this!
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stupid.I mixed syntax of Python and Octave

Comment: Pleasure. Note that on stackoverflow if an answer solves your problem you're supposed to mark it as accepted, otherwise it persists as `unanswered`

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement end with `endif` in octave (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-if-Statement.html), and also the `for` statement with `endfor` (see: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-for-Statement.html)

So the correct code would be:

```
X = magic(3)
m = size(X, 1)
p = zeros(m, 1)
theta = [1;2;1]
hypo = 1./(1.+exp(-X*theta));
for i = 1:m
    if hypo(i) > 0.5
        p(i) = 1;
    else
        p(i) = 0;
    endif
endfor
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your kindness!